# Unreleased Resource: Streams

Tags: java

Hi freinds i am getting a warning in the fortify report for the following code:

```
 if (null != serverSocket) {

     OutputStream socketOutPutStream = serverSocket
       .getOutputStream();
     if (null != socketOutPutStream) {

      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOutPutStream);
      if (null != oos) {
       int c;
       log.info("i am in Step 3 ooss " + oos);
       while ((c = mergedIS.read()) != -1) {
        oos.writeByte(c);
       }
      }
      log.info("i am in Step 4 ");

     }

    }
```

in the catch block i have mentioned :

```
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    //catch exception Vibhas added 
    log.info("UnknownHostException occured");

   } catch (IOException e) {
    //catch exception Vibhas added
    log.info("IOException occured");

   } catch (Exception e) {
    //catch exception
    //log.info("error occured in copyFile in utils-->"+e.getMessage()+"file name is-->"+destiFileName);
   }finally{

    if (null != oos){

     oos.flush();
     oos.close();

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
     //catch exception
      }

    }
```

Warning which i am getting in the fortify report is:

```
Abstract: The function copyFile() in ODCUtil.java sometimes fails to release a system resource
allocated by getOutputStream() on line 61.
Sink: ODCUtil.java:64 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOutPutStream)()
62 if (null != socketOutPutStream) {
63
64 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOutPutStream);
65 if (null != oos) {
66 int c;
```

Complete Code:

```
public boolean copyFile(InputStream is, String destiFileName) {
    boolean flag = false;
    {
        InputStream mergedIS = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream str = null;
        try {

            //Step 1 : first get the input stream of file content and file name
            // then merge into one input stream
            log.info("i am in Step 1 ");
            log.info("destiFileName got-->" + destiFileName);
            log.info("is  got in coptFile function -->" + is);
            destiFileName = "@" + destiFileName + "@";
            log.info("destiFileName sending to server-->" + destiFileName);
            str = new ByteArrayInputStream(destiFileName.getBytes());
            log.info("The ByteArrayInputStream we got is  "
                    + str.toString());
            mergedIS = new SequenceInputStream(str, is);

            //Step 2 : Make a connection to server ie DB server
            log.info("i am in Step 2 ");
            String serverIP = "172.17.119.67";
            int serverPort = 1522;
            Socket serverSocket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);

            //Step 3 : We have to write the merged inputstream to outputstream of server, ie socket of server
            log.info("i am in Step 3 ");

            //added by vibhas to resolve Unreleased resource

            if (null != serverSocket) {

                OutputStream socketOutPutStream = serverSocket
                        .getOutputStream();
                if (null != socketOutPutStream) {

                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOutPutStream);
                    if (null != oos) {
                        int c;
                        log.info("i am in Step 3 ooss " + oos);
                        while ((c = mergedIS.read()) != -1) {
                            oos.writeByte(c);
                            socketOutPutStream.close();
                        }
                    }
                    log.info("i am in Step 4 ");

                }

            }

            //Step 4 : We have to get an acknowledgment from server that , server has copied the file properly
            //this is the same .

            if (true) {
                log.info("i am in Step 4 11");
                flag = true;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            //catch exception Vibhas added 
            log.info("UnknownHostException occured");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //catch exception Vibhas added
            log.info("IOException occured");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //catch exception
            //log.info("error occured in copyFile in utils-->"+e.getMessage()+"file name is-->"+destiFileName);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != str) {
                    str.close();
                }
                if (null != ois) {
                    ois.close();
                }
                if (null != mergedIS) {
                    mergedIS.close();
                }
                if (null != oos) {
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //catch exception
            }
        }
    }
    log.info("finally returned flag-->" + flag);
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Please paste entire code fragment, properly indented. Either the above code does not compile (the catch for oos.close does not have a matching try block) or the indentation is too confusing.

Comment: Any solution guys for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not a nice try/catch structure. For one thing, ask yourself:
What would happen if `str.close();` (at the beginning of your `finally` block) throws an exception?

Better see here: [Java io ugly try-finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699209/java-io-ugly-try-finally-block)

BTW: this is ugly; `new` will never return `null`.

```
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOutPutStream);
  if (null != oos) {
```

BTW2: Are you sure you need an `ObjectOutputStream`? many people use that to write plain bytes, but that's not the idea (it's for serializing objects), and the original OutputStream would be enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is fortify report, but where are you closing `socketOutPutStream`? Does it get closed as a side-effect of closing `oos`? Even so, there is a possibility that `socketOutPutStream` is not `null` and requires closing but `oos` is null.

Comment: Hi Hemal Fortify Report is used to check the code vulnerbility against any kind of attack(specifically used for Security testing). I have closed the socketOutPutStream but still getting the same issue. I am here by putting the complete code so that you can suggest.

Comment: How can finally block thow exception, all the exceptions are Handled before controls goes to finally block. Also i am cheacking the null condion before str.close statement. Kindly clarify. Also kindly explain why there is a case for Unreleased resource mentioned in my previous code. I agree that new operator wont return null. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In the try block you are calling cloase on several obejcts. If any of these throws exception then close does not get called for the rest of objects. Try wrapping each close in separate try{ ...close(); } catch {..}

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably too late for you to care, but I have an idea. In the `finally` block, you call `flush()` before you call `close()`. But `flush()` [can throw an `IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)!