# Java code style for open stream try/finally block

Tags: java, coding-style

This is a code style question.  I notice much example code including some [examples from Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#readStream) ensure that a stream is closed in the following manner:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = acquireStream();
    ...
} finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
}
```

Note the initialization to null and check for null in the `finally` block.

I tend to write code like this:

```
InputStream in = acquireStream();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Are there advantages or disadvantages to either approach?  I like my style because I don't need the null check.  Also I like to avoid `null` when possible.  But since the Oracle style is so common in online examples, I'm wondering if mine has some hidden error.

I ask the same question for `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `java.sql.Connection`, `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, etc.  I tend to acquired the resource outside the `try` block and then close it in `finally` without a null check.  Is there anything I am missing other than stylistic differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Since ***Java 7*** there is a much nicer way to write try-finally block in regards to `Closeable` resources.

Now you can create your resources in parenthesis after the `try` keyword, like this:

```
try (init resources) {
   ...
}
```

And they will be closed ***automcatically*** after the block of code is finished. There is no need to close the streams in `finally` block.

**An example**:

```
try (
   ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipFileName);
   BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset);
) {
    // Enumerate each entry
    for (Enumeration entries = zf.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {
        // Get the entry name and write it to the output file
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String zipEntryName = ((java.util.zip.ZipEntry)entries.nextElement()).getName() + newLine;
        writer.write(zipEntryName, 0, zipEntryName.length());
    }
}
```

And after the `for` loop is done, the resources will be closed!

Answer (score 6):

The answer is, no, there is no hidden error with doing it your way. It is purely a style thing.
I typically never have a try catch finally block, only try catch blocks and try finally blocks.

They tend to end up looking like this:

```
try {
    InputStream in = acquireStream();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    ... handle exception
}
```

There is no reason to put acquireStream() in the try finally block. If in is never assigned to a valid stream, you can never close it. An explicit null check is totally unnecessary. Additionally, it is rare that you want to handle an exception on the close() differently than an exception in the main processing block.

Answer (score 3):

Typically what you have is `try`, *`catch`*, `finally`.  In that case, it's advantageous to use the standard SUN approach because you can capture any errors that occured in `acquireStream()` inside of the `try`, `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use

```
 InputStream in = null;
 try {
     in = acquireStream();
     ...
 } finally {
     if (in != null) in.close();
 }
```

if `aquireStream()` throws any checked exception and I am planning to handle it.

Else, I will use this

```
InputStream in = acquireStream();
try {
     ...
} finally {
     in.close();
}
```

*on NPE*:

I would rather let NPE to propagate and not handle any run-time exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's safer to acquire the stream within the try block.

There's another option for closing - instead of checking for null you can do the following:

```
finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
}
```

This does require Apache Commons-IO to do this, but it will do the null check for you.  It's also a nice way stylistically to do this.

Comment: See: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 0):

If your acquireStream() returned null, You will get NPE when you will try to close your stream in finally block and it will be uncaught.

Answer (score 0):

I favor the first.    Some I/O operators require they are inside a try/catch for 
some condition or other.  Also,  operations can always return null unexpectedly,
even though that is not in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I usually [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699209/java-io-ugly-try-finally-block/2699250#2699250):

```
InputStream in = null;
try { 
  in = acquire();
  ...
} finally { 
   if( in != null ) try {
       in.close();
    } catch( IOException ioe ) {
       // ignore exception while closing
    }
}
```

While closing the resource, an exception may be thrown, in which case you'll need an extra try/catch , but most of the times it's ok for me to ignore it ( I'm closing it after all ) but this is **the only** place where I use an if without braces.

I saw this from [Huckster](https://huckster.dev.java.net/) [code](https://huckster.dev.java.net/source/browse/huckster/src/com/nighthacks/huckster/CompactSlider.java?rev=1.1&view=markup)  long ago.

Comment: Does actually compile (whilst ignoring a declared, if improbable in this case, exception).

Comment: Referencing of `in` which is not definitely assigned in the `finally` clause.

Comment: @Tom, you're absolutely right. I got confused with the : `Object o;if( cond ) { o = something; } else { o = somethingelse; }` idiom. Fixed!