# Upgrading to a new Java version: code analysis

Tags: java, code-analysis

I was wandering if there is a code analysis tool able to suggest code changes when upgrading to a new Java version.

For example:

- look for `.close()` calls for autocloseable resources when upgrading to Java 7
- look for multiple `catch` clauses with the same body when upgrading to Java 7
- look for unnecessary manual boxing and unboxing when upgrading to Java 5
- ...

Are there specific tools or rules by existing ones (e.g., Checkstyle) that could help?

Comment: Side note (just in case):  Please don't migrate spam (re: *Can a unlocked iphone use an pre-paid sim card with rogers?*).  Also, don't vote to migrate when you don't know the target site's faq.  Phone and phone service questions are off topic for [su].  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ has a set of inspections tagged as "Language migration", that can help you spot locations where you could benefit from new language structures such as the enhanced for loop.

It can even automatically apply such advices to your whole codebase at once - if it's a no-risk transformation of course.

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs handles `.close()` as explained at [Java resource management: understanding Findbugs results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441853/java-resource-management-please-help-to-understand-findbugs-results) and also catches a lot of other problems.

Finsbugs deals with some problematic boxing, as when used as an operand to `==`.  [Eclipse warnings](http://javaeffective.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/the-advantages-and-traps-of-autoboxing/) can be configured to warn you about all implicit boxing/unboxing.

I don't know of anything that deals with source-wise identical `catch` bodies.

Comment: FindBugs complains only if you do not close a resource. If the resource is closed correctly it does not suggest a language migration. If the code was correct with Java 6 FindBugs will not generate any warning suggestion when migrating.

Comment: @Matteo, good point.  I think FindBugs charter is to identify problems, not find opportunities to migrate to semantically-equivalent, but more idiomatic code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a tool specifically designed for this, but there are a number tools you could use for general code auditing that will detect or suggest these types of upgrades.

1. CodePro Analytix
2. FindBugs
3. PMD (especially the CPD portion for redundant catch blocks)
4. Checkstyle

The [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) Eclipse plugin by Google has a number of really useful code analysis features that can find a number of Java 7 features you mentioned.

The Copy/Paste Detector in [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) can detect copy-pasted code in general, so it's good for finding redundant catch blocks.

Comment: CodePro Analytix is outdated and not even does not suggest anything about Java 7 but also generates false warnings for some Java 7 constructs (does for example not see that a variable is used in a try-with-resource statement). FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle do not have anything for language migration. CPD to be able to detect redundant catches should be configured with a low number of matching rows making it unusable. It would also fail to detect semantically equal blocks with different variable names.